# Inserting a variable inside a String

Tags: java, string, variables

This is probably a pretty simple issue but since I'm working with 1.3 IDE I can't use the most common method to do this.

```
String at_cmd_response = atc.send("AT+CMGS=\"+35111111111\"\r");
```

I need to introduce a string called number which holds a number like "**35191xxxxxxx**" in **at_cmd_response**. To do so, I've seen the String.format method but I can't use it due to my IDE.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what is `1.3 IDE` ?

Comment: "I've seen the String.format method but I can't use it due to my IDE". Can you clarify this? You can't use a standard Java library function because of your *IDE* ? What IDE do you use, and why doesn't it allow it?

Comment: Presumably, OP is using *Java* 1.3 (`String#format` is `@since 1.5`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like you have a modem and want to send some commands... like ***send a SMS*** or ***make a phonecall*** or similar   :-) ...

now to the question:

you need to concatenate the modem command with the parameter
in java those are strings and can be concatenated using the unary operator **+**

like:

**"AT+CMGS=\"+yourPhoneNumber+"\"\r"**

example:

```
String yourPhoneNumber = "+35111111111";
```

and now  call the method

```
atc.send("AT+CMGS=\" + yourPhoneNumber + \"\r");
```

Comment: Exactly! That's what I did to solve the issue!

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simple String concatenation (`+`) will work:

```
String at_cmd_response = atc.send("AT+CMGS=\""+number+"\"\r");
```

Comment: Exactly. 
I was typing the commas incorrectly!

Thanks a bunch Thilo!

Answer (score 0):

I use below code snippets for web element locators in Selenium.
Here variable is quoted with **'" + text + "**

```
String text="666";
String subject="Knowledge base '" + text + "' Approval Request";
```

Also for rest assured,

If I want to parameterize 3f1dd0320a0a0b99000a53f7604a2ef9 value of below URL.

https://pineapples.com/api/sn_sc/v1/fruit/items/3f1dd0320a0a0b99000a53f7604a2ef9/submit_producer
So I declared it in to a variable and using **“+sys_ID+”** I pass it.

```
  String sys_ID = "3f1dd0320a0a0b99000a53f7604a2ef9";
  RestAssured.baseURI = "https://pineapples.com";
  RestAssured.basePath = "api/sn_sc/v1/fruits/items/"+sys_ID+"/submit_producer";
```